# Remapping <C-ö> doesn't wotk

Tags: neovim

This works:

```
noremap ö l
```

This doesn't work:

```
noremap <C-ö> l
```

It seems that <C-ö/ä/ü/etc.> can't be mapped at all, or is there a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It works on my machine. Which nvim version are you using?

Comment: I've got the same issue!

Comment: Very same thing here